# How do I add tolerance to an if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, processing, p5.js

I am learning JavaScript with the p5js library and have decided to make a very basic game.

I simply want the game to end when the condition of an if statement is met.
Such as

```
if (x == y) {
>>>endcode here<<<
}
```

however I need to add a tolerance of 50 to each value

so the code would be something like

```
if (x == y (give or take 50) ){
>>>endcode here<<<
}
```

I am unsure of how to add the tolerance to the statement so I have come here for some help.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or check upper and lower borders which you might want to change borders nonsymmetrically

```
if (x =< y+50 and x >= y-50  ){
    >>>endcode here<<<
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check to see if the absolute value of the difference is less than 50:

```
if (Math.abs(x - y) <= 50) {
  // etc
}
```

I'm assuming you want to permit, eg 50 and 99, but prohibit 50 and 101. If you want the allow a difference of up to 100, then compare against 100 instead of 50:

```
if (Math.abs(x - y) <= 100) {
  // etc
}
```

Comment: 100? if tolerance of each can be up to 50, the biggest difference would be 100 :)